# Validation schema help needed

Tags: formik, yup

```js
const ValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string()
    .min(2, 'String too short!')
    .max(50, 'String too long!')
    .required('Field is required!')
    .lowercase(),
  phases: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
      sla_type: Yup.string(),
      sla: Yup.number(),
    }),
  ),
});
```

First of all I just started to learn YUP and love it. kudos to the team...

Above is my validation schema.
Under `Phases` I have two fields: `sla_type` and `sla`

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

1. If `sla_type` is empty, and `sla` is also empty no validation required, no values required
2. If `sla_type === 'minutes'`, `sla` should be min(1), max(60)
3. If `sla_type === 'hours'`, `sla` should be min(1), max(24)
4. If `sla_type === 'days'`, `sla` should be min(1), max(90)

How can I achieve this please?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [yup.when()](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema), like this:

```
const ValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    name: Yup.string()
      .min(2, 'String too short!')
      .max(50, 'String too long!')
      .required('Field is required!')
      .lowercase(),
    phases: Yup.array().of(

      Yup.object().shape({
        sla_type: Yup.string().oneOf(['minutes', 'hours', 'days']),
        sla: Yup.number().when('sla_type', (sla_type) => {
          switch (sla_type) {
            case 'minutes': 
              return Yup.number().min(1).max(60)
            case 'hours': 
              return Yup.number().min(1).max(24)
            case 'days': 
              return Yup.number().min(1).max(90)
          }
        })
      })

    )
  });
```